# No visible @interface for 'UIAttachmentBehavior' declares the selector initWithItem in DynamicsCatalog.xcodeproj

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode5

I just download DynamicsCatalog.xcodeproj from the apple developer portal but I'm getting this error:

No visible @interface for 'UIAttachmentBejavior' decleares the selector initwititem

on this line:

```
UIAttachmentBehavior *attachmentBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.square1 point:attachmentPoint attachedToAnchor:squareCenterPoint];
```

in APLAttachmentsViewController.m

This the context of that line:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDynamicAnimator* animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    UICollisionBehavior* collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.square1]];

    CGPoint squareCenterPoint = CGPointMake(self.square1.center.x, self.square1.center.y - 100.0);
    CGPoint attachmentPoint = CGPointMake(-25.0, -25.0);
    /*
     By default, an attachment behavior uses the center of a view. By using a small offset, we get a more interesting effect which will cause the view to have rotation movement when dragging the attachment.
     */
    UIAttachmentBehavior *attachmentBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.square1 point:attachmentPoint attachedToAnchor:squareCenterPoint];

    collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;

    // Show visually the attachment points
    self.redSquare.center = attachmentBehavior.anchorPoint;
    self.blueSquare.center = CGPointMake(25.0, 25.0);

    [animator addBehavior:attachmentBehavior];
    self.animator = animator;

    self.attachmentBehavior = attachmentBehavior;
}
```

Any of you knows why or how can I fix this demo code?

Comment: `initWitItem`, it's typo? miss a `h`.

Comment: Please post the actual code and the actual error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [class reference for UIAttachmentBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAttachmentBehavior_Class/Reference/Reference.html): `initWithItem:point:attachedToAnchor:` is not declared, it seems to have been removed at some point. Use one of the other initialisers:

```
– initWithItem:attachedToAnchor:
– initWithItem:attachedToItem:
– initWithItem:offsetFromCenter:attachedToAnchor:
– initWithItem:offsetFromCenter:attachedToItem:offsetFromCenter:
```

The selector you are using has actually been renamed to `initWithItem:offsetFromCenter:attachedToAnchor:`

Comment: SO should I declare on .h file or should I switch it to initWithItem:offsetFromCenter:attachedToAnchor: ?

Comment: You should use `initWithItem:offsetFromCenter:attachedToAnchor:`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the sample code was using a selector that was replaced before the final build of iOS 7. The replacement selector is `initWithItem:offsetFromCenter:attachedToAnchor:`. Additionally, that method takes `UIOffset` as the second parameter (instead of `CGPoint`).

Here is the code I used:

```
UIOffset attachmentOffset = UIOffsetMake(-25, -25);
UIAttachmentBehavior *attachmentBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.square1 offsetFromCenter:attachmentOffset attachedToAnchor:squareCenterPoint];
```

The `attachmentOffset` replaces `attachmentPoint`.